# Uploading file with python-requests - UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-requests

im trying to upload file with python-requests

```
with open('file.zip','rb') as fff:
    up = requests.post(url,files=[('file[]',fff)])
```

and getting:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte ...
```

when tried to use unicode(fff) and file was uploaded but then i downloaded it and its only 70 bytes

content of ZIP file opened in notepad:

```
<open file 'file.zip', mode 'rb' at 0x0000000002F6E030>
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace on the error?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uptest.py", line 25, in <module>
    files = {'Filedata': unicode(open('w.zip', 'rb').read()),}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdc in position 95: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Well there's your problem, you're calling the [`unicode()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) on binary, non-textual data.  Remove the call to `unicode()`.

Comment: As Adam Rosenfield suggests, your problem appears to be in your own code. If you can get a stacktrace showing the problem coming out of Requests, please post it.