# How to update httplib module?

Tags: python, upgrade, httplib

After running into this one - [previous post which recommended updating httplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065833/python-requests-trying-to-make-mailgun-sending-inline-images-sample-work) i want to upgrade my httplib module.

I have no idea how. I'm using easy_install, but when trying to call **easy_install httplib**
it didn't find matches.

Please help.

Comment: The OP there is talking about copying a version of the `httplib.py` module from a more recent version of Python 2.7. **The better option is to upgrade Python**.

Comment: i'm with python 2.7, and don't want to upgrade it. any way to do that? (getting a newer version of httplib from somewhere?)

Comment: Python 2.7 has newer releases. Install 2.7.7. You could grab the latest revision [from the Python mercurial repository](http://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/2.7/Lib/httplib.py).

Comment: install it on top of the current version of python I have? (2.7)

Comment: Yes, just upgrade it to the last point release.

Answer (score 0):

`httplib` comes **with** python package. So, if you want to updade `httplib`, you can only upgrade python.

Have you tried to update `python-requests`? Maybe your problem here.

Comment: The other post was about using the latest `requests` release with an older Python 2.7 release.

Comment: It this way, you can try to downgrade `requests` to release it work with. It is not so bad.

Comment: Who says older versions *don't* trigger the problem? I am just pointing out that upgrading `requests` won't work for that specific case.

Comment: No one, this is why you can think about this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just install `httplib2`. Here are the steps:

1. Download httplib2 onto your computer
2. `cd` into the directory when you unpacked httplib2
3. Run the command there

Alternately, you can run:

```
~$ python /path/to/httplib2/setup.py install
```

from anywhere.